# jquery form submit in vb.net

Tags: jquery, vb.net, thickbox

I am using thickbox,and everything works fine in regards to loading the page. So my div's are loaded fine and data can be inserted in the textboxes.
Now when it comes to submitting the data, i need 2 things to happen.

1. get the form to submit, so i can work on vb.net side for postback and other functions.
2. When the form is submitted i want the thickbox to close.

I am using modal=true, so i have put the `tb_remove()` on a button's onclick event. I want that sme button to do both submit to vb.net side and run tb_remove.
Does anyone know how?

aspx side code -
page name = student.aspx

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    tb_show("", "#tb_inline?height=500&amp;width=500&amp;inlineId=div1&amp;modal=true", "");
});
```

---

```
<asp:Button ID="btnsave" runat="server" text="Enter" />
```

the rest is textboxes in div1 with the btnsave and end of div1. When i click on save, i want it to goto student.aspx.vb side so i can add rest of code.

Comment: If you put an aspx button on the page, it will trigger a postback and fire that button's onClick event which you can do all of your vb.net code in, is that what you are asking for?

Comment: not really. I want the aspx:button to be inside the thickbox frame, and onclick reach the vb.net side and also close the thickbox (tb_remove())

Comment: I'm not very familiar with thickbox.  Is this something that is in an update panel?  Is it statically on the page or loaded in an iframe.  I need a little more info.

Comment: if you havent worked with jquery, this is not the question for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OnClientClick on your button so you can trigger some client side javascript before the form is posted back.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnsave" runat="server" onClientClick="tb_remove();" text="Enter" />
```

[OnClientClick (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx)